# cwrsync rsync: did not see server greeting

Tags: windows, rsync, cwrsync

Hello I try to rsync with ssh from windows to linux but I have this message:
rsync: did not see server greeting

I tried rsync ssh from linux to linux, it works.
So here is my command on windows:

```
C:\Temp\cwRsync_5.5.0_x86_Free\bin>Rsync -av -e "./ssh -i C:\Temp\id_rsa" /cygdrive/c/Temp ouistitis@192.168.1.12::.
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Temp\id_rsa':
rsync: did not see server greeting
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1648) [sender=3.1.2]
```

here is the server auth.log:

```
Mar  3 01:00:13 ORDI sshd[16605]: Accepted publickey for ouistX from 192.168.1.15 port 50590 ssh2: RSA a7:XX:b3:XX:8d:XX:4c:5a:87:XX:2a:55:a9:37:54:45
Mar  3 01:00:14 ORDI sshd[16624]: Received disconnect from 192.168.1.15: 11: disconnected by user
```

it seems there is a problem with the client, version problem?

this is the free version of cwrsync.

thx

Answer (score 4):

If you want to rsync over SSH, but you’re getting “did not see server greeting” and “error starting client-server protocol”, make sure **the destination is specified with a single colon** before filesystem path:

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh -i <somekey>" somedir <user>@<host>:somedir
```

Destination with double colon before filesystem path (like `<user>@<host>::somedir`) makes `rsync` use its daemon instead of SSH *even if you specify an SSH executable* with `-e` flag.

It is stated in rsync manual—you can see the separate section “Access via rsync daemon” using double colon before target filesystem path when the port is unspecified:

> ```
> SYNOPSIS
>        Local:  rsync [OPTION...] SRC... [DEST]
>
>        Access via remote shell:
>          Pull: rsync [OPTION...] [USER@]HOST:SRC... [DEST]
>          Push: rsync [OPTION...] SRC... [USER@]HOST:DEST
>
>        Access via rsync daemon:
>          Pull: rsync [OPTION...] [USER@]HOST::SRC... [DEST]
>                rsync [OPTION...] rsync://[USER@]HOST[:PORT]/SRC... [DEST]
>          Push: rsync [OPTION...] SRC... [USER@]HOST::DEST
>                rsync [OPTION...] SRC... rsync://[USER@]HOST[:PORT]/DEST
> ```

I stumbled across this same issue because rsync’s manual doesn’t make it very obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it seems to be an ssh version compatibility.
I finnaly choose [full sync](http://fullsync.sourceforge.net/)
which handle sftp connection with ssh key.
Not as good as rsync, but still very good

Answer (score 0):

may the port of your rsync server has been used, 
if be used, the rsync server can also start success, but has the problem like this:

rsync: did not see server greeting
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1503) [sender=3.0.6]